# text variable in sql statement - PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get my variable in a SQL-statement, put sql doesn't see it as an string.
I've searched a long time for a solution, but I can't figure it out.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
    <h2 class="title_test"></h2>
    <?php $contents = ob_get_contents(); 
    $test = 'Singer/Songwriter Nadine Shah Interview';
    $myText = (string)$contents;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT channel_id FROM guestlist_tvs WHERE title = '$myText'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row[0];
?>
```

The ob_start gets the text from h2

And myText makes a string from $contents (the value between h2).
But I don't get any result if I run the sql statement.

If I put this as the SQL-statement;

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT channel_id FROM guestlist_tvs WHERE title = '$test'");
```

it returns the right title..
So there's something wrong with converting my variable to a string, put I don't know how to fix it.

Every comment will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what does `$contents` contain? and have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: it contains the title of the video.
If I do echo $contents the title appears.

Yes I do

Comment: How `$contents` can contains the title video ? It will contains HTML output.

Comment: are there ' in the title? why not use a prepared statement to prevent sql injection and make life a lot easier?

Comment: try to escape the text first, add this: `$myText = $con->real_escape_string(contents);` should have used prepared statments

Comment: The text between <h2 class="title_test"></h2> is copied from another part of the website, that's why you don't see anything between it in this code.

But if I echo $content you'll see the title.

Comment: no sorry that returns /n

Comment: What is EXACTLY in `$contents` what does it output if you echo it.

Comment: And what if you save the whole query to a variable first and then echo it. What do you get back from it? Try this `$query = "SELECT channel_id FROM guestlist_tvs WHERE title = '$myText'";`
And then echo the `$query` variable. Maybe you can detect the anomaly in there.

Comment: Alright I've got a list of videos all with the title.
I made a jquery code that copies this title from the thumb_video and pastes it between `<h2 class="title_test"></h2>`
so in `$contents` is the text between `<h2>`, so the title that belong to the video.

@TomKriek , I used your code and it gives me the following output if I click a video:

`SELECT channel_id FROM guestlist_tvs WHERE title = '
Singer/Songwriter Nadine Shah Interview

'`

Comment: Maybe try `trim()` around the variable? Also try that query on phpmyadmin directly see if it returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<h2 class="title_test"></h2>
<?php $contents = ob_get_contents(); 
$test = 'Singer/Songwriter Nadine Shah Interview';
$myText = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim(strip_tags($contents)));
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT channel_id FROM guestlist_tvs WHERE title = '$myText'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0]; 
?>
```

How about this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment,

But unfortunately it is not working :(
the output is blank

Answer (score -1):

try it this way "SELECT channel_id FROM guestlist_tvs WHERE title = '".$test."'"